# MPAndroidChart CombinedChart crashes randomly (BarChartRenderer)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, mpandroidchart

I'm using the `CombinedChart` from [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I'm having a hard time finding what causes this crash.

It seems that `BarBuffer[] mBarBuffers` in the `BarChartRenderer` class should normally get initialized in the `initBuffers()` method, like so :

```
BarData barData = mChart.getBarData();
mBarBuffers = new BarBuffer[barData.getDataSetCount()];
```

**What I'm doing :**

```
if (!data.isEmpty()){... //Making sure there is data to plot

...

    //Create the combined data with either BarData or LineData 

...

    //Add other LineData sets
    LineData lineData = combinedData.getLineData();
    if (lineData == null) {
       combinedData.setData(otherLineData);
    } else {
       lineData.addDataSet(otherLineDataSet);
       combinedData.notifyDataChanged();
    }

...

    chart.setData(combinedData);
    chart.centerViewTo(...);
}
```

Here is the **full stackTrace** :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawDataSet(BarChartRenderer.java:136)
    at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.BarChartRenderer.drawData(BarChartRenderer.java:80)
    at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.CombinedChartRenderer.drawData(CombinedChartRenderer.java:89)
    at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:232)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16435)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15388)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15380)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16447)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2420)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15388)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15380)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15380)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15380)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15380)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15380)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3735)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3525)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchDraw(PhoneWindow.java:2766)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16447)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2752)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15388)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:286)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:292)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:327)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3030)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2834)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2446)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1323)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6718)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)`
```

Thank you for your helping ! :-)

Comment: FYI : I have created an [issue on github](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/3959) and it has been labeled as a BUG.